# Visual Studio, Compiler Error CS0012 type is not referenced in an assembly, when I have already added this reference

Tags: c#, nuget, rhino3d, eto

[image]

I don't understand.
The code shows an error asking for an assembly which I already added (Eto.dll)
The required version tallies with the current dll I have.

what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe Clean the project and build it again. If problem persists, Check the app.config file and the installed dll file, and see if their versions match

Comment: How can I check the app.config file?

Comment: Sounds like a case of DLL version hell with the **2.6.0** request.  You've also got a reference to **Eto.Platform.Wpf (2.6.1)** which I dare say depends on **Eto (2.6.1)**.   Try removing **Eto.Platform.Wpf** and re-adding it.   If that fails what usually fixes this sort of problem is to remove all NuGet packages, add an explicit package reference to **Eto** with the version you wish to use **then** add the remaining packages.  This way the packages will use **Eto** that is already present.   NuGet packages that bundle too much stuff together are a bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RhinoWindows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RhinoWindows) package can be used if you need to reference Eto.Wpf.dll in a Rhino plug-in project. The RhinoWindows and Rhinocommon packages explicitly do not copy their assemblies to the output directory during compile, since they are already included in the Rhino installation (you can see the [RhinoWindows.targets](https://nuget.info/packages/RhinoWindows/7.16.22067.13001) file on nuget.info).